# Are moving "ghosts" after waking up normal or it is sign of disorder?

Tags: mental-health, brain, vision, disorders, waking-up

Sometimes when I wake up I see moving silhouette of a human in my room. It lasts roughly 3–4 seconds. Then it fades away. These silhouettes have no detail, so I cannot sort out its faces or any details. I'm 100% sure that it is not dream and I’m not sleeping. It happens after waking up only.